# arguments passed to callbacks of Webview react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I'm trying to track the urls that a user goes through in a `WebView` in React Native.

The `WebView` element I wrote looks like this:

```
<WebView
  ref={(WEBVIEW)=>{this.WEBVIEW = WEBVIEW}}
  source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
  style={{flex: 1}}
  onLoadStart ={this.loadHandler}
/>
```

The `loadHandler` function:

```
loadHandler(data){
    console.log(data)
}
```

When I tried to execute, it gives a `Proxy` object. I don't understand how to make use of it.
[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF3S8.png)

Has anybody listed the arguments that are to be passed to all the `WebView`'s callbacks?

-----------------Edit----------------

[Expanded view of the Proxy object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVOBc.png)

Comment: can you open the proxy data and send the image ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this one, using `onNavigationStateChange`

```
<WebView
  ref={(WEBVIEW)=>{this.WEBVIEW = WEBVIEW}}
  source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
  style={{flex: 1}}
  onNavigationStateChange ={this.loadHandler.bind(this)}
/>
```

and you want the url just calling right ? just add the `loadHandler` function :

```
loadHandler(data){
    if(data.title === data.url){
    console.log(data.url)
  }
}
```

hope can solve your problem, thanks :)

Comment: onNavigationStateChange is fired when the page loading starts and ends. For a page load, it is fired two times. I want the function to be fired only once while the page loads.

Comment: i see, what inside your proxy ? can you open that and found something like url ? if yes, you can send screenshot in here please :)

Comment: I added the expanded view. Check it.

Comment: if you using onLoadStart function, it's fired two times too

Comment: i have one solution, wait a minute

Comment: @Shashank can you cek my answer again ? is that solved ?

Comment: onLoadStart gets fired only once when a URL is opened. But onNavigationStateChange gets fired 2 times. I have to write logic to not read the URL the second time it is fired. I want know what exactly is given to onLoadStart and how it can be used.

Comment: i have tried using onNavigationStateChange and add the logic in loadHandler, and the result is just show the url once, the second and third time is it fired it can not be showed (just check the code), but if you want explore about onLoadStart you can explore it :)